# Algorithm for determining if a string is a prefix of a date in some range

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, validation, date

I'm trying to validate a textbox in VBA so that a user cannot enter values that couldn't possibly end up being a date within some interval. Is there a good away to determine if a string can be the prefix of a date subject to some interval? For example, if the user needs to enter a date between 1/1/2018 and 12/31/2018, I want to "02/20" to pass but not something like "02/29". Dates can be in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format, although I'll take a good algorithm for just one of the formats. I'm not sure of a way to do this without a lot of loops or conditions.

Edit: I think I found a good solution if anyone wants to check it.

```
Private Sub mMainControl_Change()

    Dim vIsValid As Boolean
    Dim vPrefixLength As Integer
    Dim vDatePrefix As String

    vDatePrefix = CStr(mMainControl.Value)
    vPrefixLength = Len(vDatePrefix)

    If vPrefixLength = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not InitialCheck(vDatePrefix, mMinValue, mMaxValue) Then
        vIsValid = False
    ElseIf mMaxValue - mMinValue > 365 Then
        If Not FullYearCheck(vDatePrefix, mMinValue, mMaxValue) Then vIsValid = False
    Else
        If Not PartYearCheck(vDatePrefix, mMinValue, mMaxValue) Then vIsValid = False
    End If

    If Not vIsValid Then mMainControl.Value = Left(vDatePrefix, Min(10, vPrefixLength - 1))

End Sub

Private Function InitialCheck(ByVal DatePrefix As String, ByVal MinDate As Date, ByVal MaxDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim vPrefixLength As Integer
    Dim vTestDate As Variant

    vPrefixLength = Len(DatePrefix)

    If vPrefixLength > 10 Or Not DatePrefix Like Left("##/##/####", vPrefixLength) Then
        InitialCheck = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    vTestDate = CDate(DatePrefix & Right("01/01/1996", 10 - vPrefixLength))
    vTestDate = CDate(DatePrefix & Right("01/00/1984", 10 - vPrefixLength))
    On Error GoTo 0

    InitialCheck = Not IsEmpty(vTestDate)

End Function

Private Function FullYearCheck(ByVal DatePrefix As String, ByVal MinDate As Date, ByVal MaxDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer, vPrefixLength As Integer, vMinPrefixYear As Integer, vMaxPrefixYear As Integer
    Dim vFullDate As Variant

    vPrefixLength = Len(DatePrefix)
    If vPrefixLength > 6 Then
        vMinPrefixYear = CInt(Right(DatePrefix, vPrefixLength - 6) & Left("0000", 10 - vPrefixLength))
        vMaxPrefixYear = CInt(Right(DatePrefix, vPrefixLength - 6) & Left("9999", 10 - vPrefixLength))
        If Year(MinDate) < vMinPrefixYear Then MinDate = DateSerial(vMinPrefixYear, 1, 1)
        If Year(MaxDate) > vMaxPrefixYear Then MaxDate = DateSerial(vMaxPrefixYear, 12, 31)
    End If

    For i = 0 To Year(MaxDate) - Year(MinDate)
        vFullDate = DatePrefix & Right("01/01/" & CStr(Year(MinDate) + i), 10 - vPrefixLength)
        If ValidByMonth(vFullDate, MinDate, MaxDate) Or ValidByDay(vFullDate, MinDate, MaxDate) Then Exit For
        vFullDate = DatePrefix & Right("01/00/" & CStr(Year(MinDate) + i), 10 - vPrefixLength)
        If ValidByMonth(vFullDate, MinDate, MaxDate) Or ValidByDay(vFullDate, MinDate, MaxDate) Then Exit For Else vFullDate = Empty
    Next i

    FullYearCheck = Not IsEmpty(vFullDate)

End Function

Private Function PartYearCheck(ByVal DatePrefix As String, ByVal MinDate As Date, ByVal MaxDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer, vPrefixLength As Integer
    Dim vFullDate As Variant

    vPrefixLength = Len(DatePrefix)

    For i = 0 To MaxDate - MinDate
        vFullDate = DatePrefix & Right(Format(CStr(MinDate + i), "mm/dd/yyyy"), 10 - vPrefixLength)
        If ValidByMonth(vFullDate, MinDate, MaxDate) Then Exit For
        vFullDate = DatePrefix & Right(Format(CStr(MinDate + i), "dd/mm/yyyy"), 10 - vPrefixLength)
        If ValidByDay(vFullDate, MinDate, MaxDate) Then Exit For Else vFullDate = Empty
    Next i

    PartYearCheck = Not IsEmpty(vFullDate)

End Function

Private Function ValidByMonth(ByVal DateString As String, ByVal MinDate As Date, ByVal MaxDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim vTestDate As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    vTestDate = CDate(MonthName(Left(DateString, 2)) & " " & Mid(DateString, 4, 2) & ", " & Right(DateString, 4))
    If vTestDate < MinDate Or vTestDate > MaxDate Then vTestDate = Empty
    On Error GoTo 0

    ValidByMonth = Not IsEmpty(vTestDate)

End Function

Private Function ValidByDay(ByVal DateString As String, ByVal MinDate As Date, ByVal MaxDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim vTestDate As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    vTestDate = CDate(MonthName(Mid(DateString, 4, 2)) & " " & Left(DateString, 2) & ", " & Right(DateString, 4))
    If vTestDate < MinDate Or vTestDate > MaxDate Then vTestDate = Empty
    On Error GoTo 0

    ValidByDay = Not IsEmpty(vTestDate)

End Function
```

Comment: 2/29 should pass roughly ever 4 years.

Comment: All dates have the same year?

Comment: There's no limit on the lower/upper bound. You can say lower = 11/18/1932, upper = 12/15/5354.

Comment: Then how to test the prefix without the year?  Do you just mean "invalid" dates  like "12/34" for example ?  Even your "2/29" example falls over when evaluated within a multi-year window

Comment: Whether something is valid or not should be determined partially based on the constraints. "12/34" should always fail, "2/29" should sometimes fail.

Comment: So - 01/11 should pass and 11/01 should  pass, but how to determine which is which? Using a datepicker is so much safer.

Comment: if the upper and lower bounds are several years apart, when should 2/29 pass? as long as there's at least one leap year in the interval?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Yes Tim, you understand correctly. I would prefer to use a date picker but I don't want people to have to install the package for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you reject `02/29` and `29/02` Excel might do the rest for you if you input into a General format cell and then detect that cell's format with `=CELL("format",cr)` (**c**olumn/**r**ow to suit).